# HPUX: missing symbol

Tags: hp-ux

```
/opt/samba3/sbin/winbindd -d 100 -i
```

produce

```
/usr/lib/hpux32/dld.so: Unsatisfied code symbol '_nss_winbind_initgroups_dyn' in load module '/usr/lib/hpux32/libnss_winbind.so.1'.
Killed
```

How to check?
I have to recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,must modify configure of samba
hpux line must be

```
 *hpux11*)
                NSSSONAMEVERSIONSUFFIX=".1"
                WINBIND_NSS_EXTRA_OBJS="../nsswitch/winbind_nss_solaris.o \
                    ../nsswitch/winbind_nss_linux.o"
```

instead of

```
*hpux11*)
                NSSSONAMEVERSIONSUFFIX=".1"
                WINBIND_NSS_EXTRA_OBJS="../nsswitch/winbind_nss_solaris.o"
```

Compile fine,launch winbindd ok,but id doensn't report the user
(same thing for pwget),i have configured nsswitch.conf
probably something bad in nsswitch wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Making a diff with old module(the module of cifs server by hp) i see

```
nm -n libnss_winbind.so.1*|grep _nss_winbind_initgroups_dyn

[185]    |            0|       0|FUNC |GLOB |0|   UNDEF|_nss_winbind_initgroups_dyn
[142]    |     67178688|    2080|FUNC |GLOB |0|   .text|_nss_winbind_initgroups_dyn
```

My module in undefined in funtction _nss_winbind_initgroups_dyn
i have compiled samba with

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/samba3 --with-lockdir=/var/opt/samba3/locks --with-privatedir=/var/opt/samba3/private --with-configdir=/etc/opt/samba3 --localstatedir=/var/opt/samba3 --with-krb5=/opt/krb5 --enable-nss-wrapper --enable-socket-wrapper --enable-static --enable-pthreadpool --with-libaddns --with-automount --with-quotas  --with-aio-support  --with-libiconv==/usr/local \
--with-pam \
--with-winbind \
--with-readline \
--with-lockdir=/var/opt/samba3/locks \
--with-statedir=/var/opt/samba3/locks \
--with-cachedir=/var/opt/samba3/cache \
--with-piddir=/var/opt/samba3/locks \
--with-logfilebase=/var/opt/samba3/log \
ac_cv_lib_rt_fdatasync=no \
ac_cv_have_fdatasync_decl=no \
ac_cv_lib_ext_rt_fdatasync=no \
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/krb5/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/krb5/lib -Wl,+b,/opt/krb5/lib -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err'
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks